# Find the analytical solution of a stochastic integral equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> Find the analytical solution of the stochastic integral equation
>   $$\tag1
>   X(t) = -\frac18-\int_0^t\frac14sX(s)ds-\int_0^t\frac{1}{40}X(s)dB_H(s)
> $$
>   where $(B_H(t))_{t\ge0}$ is a fractional Brownian motion, i.e. a continuous Gaussian process with $B_H(0)=0$, $\mathbb E[B_H(t)]=0$ $\forall t$, covariance $\mathbb E[B_H(t)B_H(s)] = \frac12(|t|^{2H}+|s|^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H})$ and $H\in(0,1)$.

---

> SOLUTION
>   $$\tag2
>   X(t) = -\frac18\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{40}B_H(t)-\frac{t^2}{8}-\frac{t^{2H}}{3200}\Big)
> $$
>   P.S. I have not to verify that this is the solution, but rather to find it from $(1)$.

---

I tried to apply the Ito formula for fractional integrals
[image]

where $f(s,x) : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a function of $C^{1,2}(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R)$.

Using $f(t,X(t)) = \log X(t)$ I got

$$
  \log X(t) = \log X(0)+\int_0^t\frac{1}{X(s)}dX(s)+H\int_0^t-\frac{1}{X^2(s)}s^{2H-1}ds+\underbrace{\int_0^t\frac{\partial\log X(s)}{\partial s}ds}_{=0\ ?}
$$

and by substituting $dX(s) = -\frac14sX(s)ds-\frac{1}{40}X(s)dB_H(s)$ (obtained from $(1)$ by differentiating)

$$\begin{align*}
  \log\frac{X(t)}{X(0)} &= \int_0^t \Big(-\frac14sds-\frac{1}{40}dB_H(s)\Big)+\underbrace{H\int_0^t-\frac{1}{X^2(s)}s^{2H-1}ds}_{=\ ?} \\
  &=-\frac{t^2}{8}-\frac{1}{40}B_H(t)+?
\end{align*}$$

Then by taking exponential both sides

$$
  X(t) = X(0)\exp\Big(-\frac{t^2}{8}-\frac{1}{40}B_H(t)+?\Big)
$$

which partially is equal to $(2)$. Moreover I notice that $H\int_0^ts^{2H-1}ds = t^{2H}/2$, which is also contained in $(2)$. But I don't know how to deal with $\frac{1}{X^2(s)}$.

---

Maybe another way is to assume that the solution is of the form
$$
  X(t) = a\exp(bB_H(t)+c(t))
$$
but how to find $a, b\in\mathbb R$ and the real function $c$?

Comment: What do you mean by integration against fBm for $H<1/2$?

Comment: i think the answer is on yuliya mishura's stochastic calculus for fBm

Comment: Defining integration against fBm with bad regularity is highly nontrivial and nonunique.

Comment: what about $H > 1/2$? is it possible to find the solution in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't apply Itô's formula correctly. The Itô formula which you stated at the beginning of your calculation applies for expressions of the form $f(t,B_H(t))$ - but in your computation you need to compute the stochastic differential of $f(t,X_t)$. Compare this with the situation in classical stochastic calculus (i.e. for Brownian motion): Itô's formula for Brownian motion looks different than Itô's formula for general Itô processes.

Here is the version of Itô's formula which you need to solve the problem: If $$X_t = \int_0^t b(s) \,ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s) \, dB_H(s)$$

then (assuming everything is well-defined)

\begin{align*} f(t,X_t) -f(0,X_0) &= \int_0^t \partial_s f(s,X_s) \, ds + \int_0^t \partial_x f(s,X_s) \, d\color{red}{X_s} \\ &+ H \int_0^t \partial_x^2 f(s,X_s) \color{red}{\sigma(s)^2} s^{2H-1} \, ds. \tag{1} \end{align*}

Note that for $X_t = B_H(t)$ we get, as a particular case, the Itô formula which you stated.

Applying Itô's formula $(1)$ for $f(t,x) = \log x$, it follows that

\begin{align*} \frac{\log X_t}{\log X_0} &= \int_0^t -\frac{1}{4} s \, ds - \frac{1}{40} \int_0^t dB_H(s) + H \int_0^t - \frac{1}{X_s^2} \color{red}{\left( \frac{1}{40} X_s\right)^2} s^{2H-1} \, ds \\ &= - \frac{t^2}{8} - \frac{1}{40} B_H(t) - \frac{1}{3200} t^{2H}.\end{align*}

(The term in red is the one which is missing in your calculation.) Hence,

$$X_t = X_0 \exp \left(-\frac{t^2}{8} - \frac{1}{40} B_H(t) - \frac{1}{3200} t^{2H} \right).$$

Comment: Thank you very much! While I study your answer, could you tell me if considering the logarithm of $X_t$ (equation (1) of my question) is completely correct? I'm asking since all terms in $X_t$ are negative, so it seems that log is not defined. But maybe the results of the two integrals in $X_t$ are negative, hence the two terms turn positive.

Comment: @soundwave Since $X_t$ is (strictly) negative, you can apply itô's formula for $-X_t$ to compute the stochastic differential of $\log(-X_t)$. This doesn't really change much about the calculation

Comment: Do you know a source for the Ito formula that you used? I found several papers and books but there are several Ito formulas w.r.t. the fBm, and I cannot find the one you used.

Comment: p.s. the books I was talking about are **Mishura** "Stochastic Calculus for Fractional Brownian Motion and Related Processes" and **Biagini, Hu, Oksendal, Zhang** "Stochastic Calculus for Fractional Brownian Motion and Applications". The closest Ito formula to yours which I could find is https://i.imgur.com/09yPMAA.png which is in the Mishura book.

Comment: Moreover, is the Ito formula that you stated based on the pathwise approach or on the Malliavin/Skorohod approach?

Comment: @soundwave Sorry, I don't have a reference for the formula right now and I won't have the opportunity to look it up any time soon

Comment: Ok don't worry, anyway could you help in the identification of the framework in which the formula is defined? That is, the integral w.r.t to the fBm in your equation $(1)$ is a pathwise integral or a Skorohod integral?